# Delayed_job suddenly doesn't seem to do anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a scraper set up to use delayed_job so that it runs in the background.

```
class Scraper
  def do_scrape
    # do some scraping stuff
  end
  handle_asynchronously :do_scrape
end
```

Now I can comment out the `handle_asynchronously` line, open the console and run the scraper just fine. It does exactly what I expect it to do.

However, when I try to fire the scrape as a delayed job, it doesn't seem to do anything at all. Further to that, it doesn't seem to log anything important either.

Here's how my log looks from enqueueing a job to running `rake jobs:work`.

```
County Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "counties".* FROM "counties" WHERE "counties"."name" = 'Fermanagh' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (20.5ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("attempts", "created_at", "failed_at", "handler", "last_error", "locked_at", "locked_by", "priority", "run_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["attempts", 0], ["created_at", Mon, 30 May 2011 21:19:25 UTC +00:00], ["failed_at", nil], ["handler", "--- 

# serialized object omitted for conciseness

nmethod_name: :refresh_listings_in_the_county_without_delay\nargs: []\n\n"], ["last_error", nil], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["priority", 0], ["run_at", Mon, 30 May 2011 21:19:25 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 30 May 2011 21:19:25 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE (locked_by = 'host:David-Tuites-MacBook-Pro.local pid:7743' AND locked_at > '2011-05-30 17:19:32.116511') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 42]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

As you can see, it seems to just inset a job and then delete it straight away? This scraping method should take at least a few minutes.

The worst part is, it was working perfectly last night and I can't think of a single thing I'm doing differently. I tried fixing the gem to a previous version incase it was updated recently but doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured your delayed job to delete failed jobs? Look for the following setting in your initializer:
`Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = true`

If yes then set it to false and look into the delayed_jobs table for the exception due to which it failed and debug further.

Comment: I din't have that set at all but I put it in and set it to false anyway. Now I'm told that `Job failed to load: allocator undefined for Proc. Handler`. A bit of googling tells me that I may be getting this error because the job I'm trying to delay is too complicated so I guess I'll try to deal with that. Thanks.

Comment: I simplified things a little and that seems to have helped.

Comment: @duckyfuzz I'm getting the same error, could you explain what you mean by the job you're trying to delay was 'too complicated?' and how did you simplify it?

Comment: @DavidTuite I am getting the same error could you please tell me what you have done to solve this problem it would be of great help.

Comment: @abhas It's a long time ago but if I remember correctly the problem was that DJ has to serialize the Scraper instance and store it in the database. If your Scraper class is large and complicated the DJ can choke. So, I moved the async behavior out into a separate, simpler class and everything worked.